# iOS Screenshot as System.Drawing.Bitmap (Xamarin) from Background App

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, bitmap

For a **private app** (=not to be published on any appstore) on a **jailbroken iOS-Device** I need to take screenshots of the entire screen from being sent to the background.

Similar questions have been posted

- [iOS: Is it possible to take screenshots while running as a background task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548894/ios-is-it-possible-to-take-screenshots-while-running-as-a-background-task) which concluded that it would be impossible on non-jailbroken devices due to iOS's security sandbox
- [How to take screenshots of running iPhone from background app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085142/how-to-take-screenshots-of-running-iphone-from-background-app) is yet pending, but also seems to target non-jailbroken devices
- [How to take screenshot of entire screen on a Jailbroken iOS Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369014/how-to-take-screenshot-of-entire-screen-on-a-jailbroken-ios-device) (and somewhat similar [jailbroken iOS taking screenshot from background app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338416/jailbroken-ios-taking-screenshot-from-background-app) ) seems to be close to what I am looking for, but  the code is written in Objective C and makes use of a mysterious private function *_UICreateScreenUIImage()* of which I don't know in which module it is defined (so I don't know how to declare it as an external function). Also the screenshot is returned as a UIImage (see http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage/ ) which I yet don't know how to convert to a System.Drawing.Bitmap (see https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Drawing.Bitmap/ ).

The following is a post of my code. I am looking for help with the implementation of `private System.Drawing.Bitmap ShootScreen()`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

namespace StackOverflowSnippets
{
    public sealed class ScreenshooterThread
    {
        private Thread _t = null;                   // Thread-Object: Execution-Helper
        private Boolean _terminate = false;         // Stop current execution?
        private Int32 _intervalMS = 0;              // Take Screenshots every ? MS
        private Queue<Bitmap> _q;                   // Queue to store the Screenshots

        #region Interface
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Screenshooter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intervalMS">Defines every how many MS a screenshot should be taken</param>
        public ScreenshooterThread(Int32 intervalMS = 200)
        {
            _intervalMS = intervalMS;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts taking Screenshots
        /// </summary>
        public void Run()
        {
            if(this.IsRunning || this.IsTerminating)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("ScreenshooterThread is currently running or terminating");
            }

            lock (this)
            {
                _terminate = false;
                _t = new Thread(this.DoWork);
                _t.Start();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops taking Screenshots
        /// </summary>
        public void Stop()
        {
            if (!this.IsRunning) return; if (this.IsTerminating) return;

            lock(this)
            {
                _terminate = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the Thread is currently running
        /// </summary>
        public Boolean IsRunning
        {
            get
            {
                if (_t == null) return false;

                return _t.IsAlive;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether Thread-Termination has been invoked
        /// </summary>
        public Boolean IsTerminating
        {
            get
            {
                return _terminate;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a Screenshot from the Queue. Returns null if none available
        /// </summary>
        public Bitmap Deqeue()
        {
            lock(_q)
            {
                if (_q.Count < 1) return null;
                return _q.Dequeue();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Implementation Details
        /// <summary>
        /// Add a Screenshot to the Queue
        /// </summary>
        private void Enqueue(Bitmap b)
        {
            lock(_q)
            {
                _q.Enqueue(b);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Task-Implementation while running
        /// </summary>
        private void DoWork()
        {
            while(!_terminate)
            {
                if (_intervalMS > 0) Thread.Sleep(_intervalMS);

                this.Enqueue(this.ShootScreen());
            }

            this.CleanUp();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes a Screenshot of the device even if the app is in the Background
        /// </summary>
        private System.Drawing.Bitmap ShootScreen()
        {
            // System.Drawing.Bitmap supported by Xamarin
            // https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Drawing.Bitmap/

            // Method in ObjC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369014/how-to-take-screenshot-of-entire-screen-on-a-jailbroken-ios-device

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Preparing for next launch
        /// </summary>
        private void CleanUp()
        {
            lock(this)
            {
                _terminate = false;
                _t = null;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

PS: The screenshots need to be a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` because I need to perform Pixelwise operations on it afterwards

**EDIT 1**

Upon further investigation I found on http://sharpmobilecode.com/introduction-to-xamarin-what-it-is-what-it-isnt/ the following paragraph

> For example, let’s say you have existing C# code that uses
>   System.Drawing.Bitmap. It’s a common library you wrote that multiple
>   Desktop apps reference. A possible method looks something like this:
>
> ```
> using System.Drawing; 
>
> public Bitmap GetBitmapFromCache(string fileName) 
> { 
>    return (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(fileName); 
> }
> ```
>
> If you were to compile this method in a Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android app,you would get a compile error.  Huh?  Upon
>   further investigation, you would see that `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and
>   `System.Drawing.Image` are not define.  What!?!?  That’s valid C#
>   syntax!  Upon further investigation, you only see a few classes in
>   `System.Drawing` are actually defined (RectangleF, PointF, etc).  Where
>   the heck is Bitmap and Image?  Well, there is a good reason these
>   classes are not implemented in the Mono Framework.  It’s because they
>   are not cross platform compatible.
>
> What does that mean exactly?  Let’s take a look at the System.Drawing
>   documentation on MSDN.  It states, “The System.Drawing namespace
>   provides access to GDI+ basic graphics functionality.”.  What is GDI+?
>   GDI+ (Graphics Device Interface) is a graphics library (Win32) that is
>   specific to the Windows Operating System.  So underneath the hood of a
>   System.Drawing.Bitmap, is a Win32 implementation that ties into the
>   Windows Desktop/Server Operating systems.    That means
>   System.Drawing.Bitmap and System.Drawing.Image are platform dependent,
>   and only work on Windows Desktop/Server apps.  You will not be able to
>   use these classes on iOS app, Android apps, or even Windows Phone
>   apps.  So how can you use this current C# code in an iOS or Android
>   app?  With a slight modification like this:
>
> ```
> public byte[] GetBitmapFromCache(string fileName) 
> { 
>     return File.ReadAllBytes(fileName); 
> }
> ```
>
> iOS and Android have no concept of GDI+ bitmap
>   (System.Drawing.Bitmap), however, each platform knows how to convert
>   an array of bytes into their own implementation of a bitmap.  Using
>   iOS, you can create a UIImage from an array of bytes, and in Android
>   you can create an Android.Graphics.Bitmap from that same array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated under http://sharpmobilecode.com/introduction-to-xamarin-what-it-is-what-it-isnt/ it is not possible to create a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` because the `System.Drawing` namespace provides access to GDI+ basics graphics functionality which is specific to the Windows OS and therefore simply not available on iOS.

It is however possible to create a screenshot as an `UIImage` as follows

1. [How to take screenshot of entire screen on a Jailbroken iOS Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369014/how-to-take-screenshot-of-entire-screen-on-a-jailbroken-ios-device) showed, that there exists a private function `_UICreateScreenUIImage(void)` that returns the desired screenshot. In order to access this function, it must be declared

   ```
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   using ObjCRuntime;

   [DLLImport(/*ObjCRuntime.*/Constants.UIKitLibrary)]
   extern static IntPtr _UICreateScreenUIImage();
   ```
2. When called, the returned IntPtr points to a native UIImage and needs to be wrapped into a managed object, which is done by `Runtime.GetNSObject(IntPtr)`

   ```
   IntPtr ptr = _UICreateScreenUIImage();
   UIImage uiimg = Runtime.GetNSObject(ptr) as UIImage;
   ```

   The resulting `uiimg` contains the screenshot

The attached picture contains a minimalistic example on how to create a screenshot and save it as a `.jpeg`

[image: Minimalistic example on how to create and save a screenshot]

And an example of what a screenshot might look like when the app is in the background

[image: Picture of what a screenshot looks like]